# What approach should I take when implementing a horizontal GridView in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I need to implement the horizontal (magazine style) list. The apps that do this quite good (in my opinion) are Flipboard and Zite. I wondered if this is possible to implement into a Xamarin.Forms application with existing resources.

In Xamarin.Forms, you have an excellent `View` that is the `ListView`. This ListView has an ItemSource and an ItemTemplate property where you can bind your ViewModel to the ItemSource and you can bind your `TextCell` class to your ItemTemplate.

I'm searching for the exact same thing except that you can modify the ItemTemplate to a custom class I make myself. The reason I need this is that I need a more complex layout than `TextCell`and the `ListView` only scrolls vertically.

I like the MVVM pattern very much and I need something that exactly fits into this pattern. Now, I looked into some implementations:

- https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs
- http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18627/gridview-with-itemssource

## Option 1

In the Xamarin.Forms.Labs, there is a `GridView`, but this view doesn't expand to its parent in my implementation although I am setting the following:

```
var grid = GridView {
    ItemWidth = 50,
    ItemHeight = 50,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
};
```

My ItemSource is tied to my ViewModel (which I am 100% sure of it is providing items. I know that because if I swap this `GridView` for a `ListView`, there are items.):

`grid.ItemSource = ViewModel.Items;`

And my ItemTemplate:

```
var cell = new DataTemplate(typeof(TextCell));
            cell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Title");
            cell.SetBinding(TextCell.TextProperty, "Description");
            gridView.ItemTemplate = cell;
```

Now, I know there are some problems with the `GridView` and that the implementation is only for iOS right now according to [this](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/commit/dda64e02dd1a3fb72f71296d0ea3604fef0f5df9).

## Option 2

In the second post they mention a `WrapLayout`. Although it shows some items being added via its Children property, it doesn't show any implementation with MVVM. Besides that, the implementation is nowhere near finished.

I can take this project as a base and expand it to my needs. But I feel there has to be a lot of work done for this to work in my scenario.

Does anybody know any other resources that better fit my needs than these two? For which option should I go if there aren't any resources available (I know there must be something available since Zite and Flipboard already done it)?

Comment: Hi Jack, did you manage to get around your problem? I'm facing something similar and would like a WrapLayout with an ItemSource.

Comment: Hi Jason, I didn't managed to come up with a solution. The options I had were: go with Xamarin.Forms.Labs, which only had a beta version of the GridView and the Android implementation wasn't written at the point I needed it. I discussed the issue with my manager, and we decided to stick with a ListView for both platforms. That was a couple of monts ago, so maybe there are different alternatives as of now. Let me know if you found anything interesting, because I might need it in the future as well.

Answer (score -3):

I dont know flipboard or zite but you try could something like this.

```cs
var grid = new Grid()
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    ColumnDefinitions = new ColumnDefinitionCollection()
    {
        new ColumnDefinition(){ Width = new GridLength(250, GridUnitType.Absolute) },
        new ColumnDefinition(){ Width = new GridLength(250, GridUnitType.Absolute) },
        new ColumnDefinition(){ Width = new GridLength(250, GridUnitType.Absolute) },
        new ColumnDefinition(){ Width = new GridLength(250, GridUnitType.Absolute) },
        new ColumnDefinition(){ Width = new GridLength(250, GridUnitType.Absolute) },
        new ColumnDefinition(){ Width = new GridLength(250, GridUnitType.Absolute) }
    },
    RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection()
    {
        new RowDefinition(){ Height = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star) },
        new RowDefinition(){ Height = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star) },
        new RowDefinition(){ Height = new GridLength(1,GridUnitType.Star) }
    }
};
var scrollview = new ScrollView() { Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal };
scrollview.Content = grid;
```

Comment: You specified a Grid. So you are suggesting that I should build up the layout myself? How to maintain items in the grid then?